# How do I push an entity onto an Rx Observable?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a class that is going to be responsible for generating events on an frequent but irregular interval, that other classes must consume and operate on.  I want to use [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577612) for this task.

The consumer side of this is very straightforward; I have my consumer class implementing `IObserver<Payload>` and all seems well.  The problem comes on the producer class.

Implementing `IObservable<Payload>` directly (that is, putting my own implementation for `IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Payload> )` is, according to the documentation, not recommended.  It suggests instead composing with the `Observable.Create()` set of functions.  Since my class will run for a long time, I've tried creating an Observable with `var myObservable = Observable.Never()`, and then, when I have new Payloads available, calling `myObservable.Publish(payloadData)`.  When I do this, though, I don't seem to hit the `OnNext` implementation in my consumer.

I think, as a work-around, I can create an event in my class, and then create the Observable using the `FromEvent` function, but this seems like an overly complicated approach (i.e., it seems weird that the new hotness of Observables 'requires' events to work).  Is there a simple approach I'm overlooking here?  What's the 'standard' way to create your own Observable sources?

Comment: As a general rule, if you find yourself implementing either `IObservable<T>` or `IObserver<T>` then you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `new Subject<Payload>` and call it's `OnNext` method to send an event. You can `Subscribe` to the subject with your observer.

The use of Subjects is often debated. For a thorough discussion on the use of Subjects (which links to a primer), see [here](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) - but in summary, this use case sounds valid (i.e. it probably meets the local + hot criteria).

As an aside, overloads of Subscribe accepting delegates may remove the need for you to provide an implemention of `IObserver<T>`.

Comment: The concept of the Subject<T> and the links provided really helped me understand this more completely.

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.Never()` doesn't "send" notifications, you should use `Observable.Return(yourValue)`

If you need a guide with concrete examples i recommend reading [Intro to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html)

Comment: I may be very confused here...  If I use Observable.Return, won't that observable only have the one value?  I need one that stays alive for a while, so that I can periodically push more values onto it as I compute them.

Comment: You should really read "Intro to Rx", IObservable<T> is a sequence of events, when the Observer gets OnNext(T value) you get the latest value to work with.

Comment: According to the docs, "One final essential factory method or primitive constructor is called Return. Its role is to represent a singleelement
sequence, just like a single-cell array would be in the world of IEnumerable sequences. The behavior
observed by subscribed observers is two messages: OnNext with the value and OnCompleted signaling the end
of the sequence has been received:
 IObservable<int> source = Observable.Return(42);
Running this code produces the following output:
 OnNext: 42
 OnCompleted".  I don't want the completed signal, I want the sequence to stay open/alive.

Comment: Whats your source?, i wrote "sequence of events" because is the simplest concept, for example the function `FromEvent` hooks on .Net events and every time the system triggers the "event" it sends OnNext() to your Observer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I come across a better way of doing it, what I've settled on for now is the use of a `BlockingCollection`.

```
var _itemsToSend = new BlockingCollection<Payload>();
IObservable<MessageQueuePayload> _deliverer =
_itemsToSend.GetConsumingEnumerable().ToObservable(Scheduler.Default);
```